# SQL Server 2008 R2: Prepare a recursive query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the table with the two columns namely `cola` and `colb` as shown below:

Table : `Test`

```
create table Test
(
   cola int,
   colb int
);
```

Records I have entered are:

```
Cola   Colb
------------
1      2
1      3
1      4
2      5
2      6
2      3
3      2
3      4
3      7
3      10
10     11
11     12
11     13
11     14
12     15
13     16 
14     99
15     88
16     77
```

**Note**: Now I want to show the only records who are connected with value I have pass. For example If I pass the value as `1` then it should display me the connected number to it and form connect like a tree.

[image]

[image]

For this I am using the following script:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT Cola,Colb 
    FROM Test
    WHERE Cola IN 
    (
        SELECT Colb AS Colb
        FROM Test 
        WHERE Cola = '1'
    ) 
),
outerCTE1 AS
( 
    SELECT Cola,Colb FROM CTE 
    UNION
    SELECT Cola,Colb FROM Test
    WHERE Cola IN (SELECT Colb FROM CTE)
),
OuterCTE2 AS
(
    SELECT Cola,Colb FROM OuterCTE1
    WHERE Colb NOT IN (SELECT Cola FROM CTE)
    UNION
    SELECT Cola,Colb
    FROM Test
    WHERE Cola = '1'
),
lastCTE AS
(   
    SELECT Cola,Colb,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Colb ORDER BY Cola) rn FROM outerCTE2
)
SELECT Cola,Colb FROM lastCTE
WHERE rn <=1
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Cola = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,Cola;
```

**But**: The problem is that I am just able to produce records till the 11 but I want to produce all the records till the end whichever match found till the end. So how to write a recursive query for this situation?

Comment: 2 --> 3 and 3--> 2.. how do you want to handle this case?

Comment: @DarkKnight, Yeah! That is the biggest task I feel. If 2-->3 is already appeared above then 3-->2 should not appear in the below table set.

Comment: @DarkKnight, And If I have passed `3` as my ID then 3-->2 will appear first and 2-->3 should not appear next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ;WITH CTE AS
    (
       SELECT COLA,COLB,','+CAST(COLA AS VARCHAR(MAX))+',' AS CHCK FROM TEST WHERE COLA=1
       UNION ALL
       SELECT C1.COLA,C1.COLB,C.CHCK+CAST(C1.cola AS VARCHAR(MAX))+','
       FROM CTE C INNER JOIN TEST C1 ON  C.colb = C1.cola
       WHERE CHARINDEX(','+CAST(C.colb AS VARCHAR(MAX))+',',C.CHCK)=0
    )

   SELECT DISTINCT COLA,COLB FROM CTE ORDER BY COLA
```

Comment: If I pass ID = `1`  then it's giving an error : `The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.`

Comment: You need to add "**option (maxrecursion 0)**" at the end of the SELECT statement. Please refer to [maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted](http://www.kodyaz.com/forums/thread/1761.aspx) and for a [SQL Recursive Function Sample](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-t-sql-split-function.aspx)

Comment: @Eralper, Yes! I did but the result is getting repeated for long while with the no end. Still getting an wrong result. Well! Thank you for your valuable comment.

Comment: Actually following rows are causing an infinitive loop "2      3" and "3      2"

Comment: @Eralper, Oh! I am trying to resolve that. If you come to know anything about it then please have a comment here. Thanks

Comment: @DarkKnight, A step closer I said. But still getting an 2-->3 and 3-->2. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @Dark Knight, Yup! I solved it. By using `ROW_NUMBER()`. Thank you so much for your assistance.

Comment: @DarkKnight, Please check the new post regarding this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32961885/sql-server-2008-r2-recursive-query